# About evaluation of processing time of an code in octave

Tags: time, octave

The `cputime ();` returns the CPU time used by an Octave session. [Here](https://techlogbook.wordpress.com/2008/03/17/measure-processing-time-in-octave/), a way is stated to measure the processing time of a code.

```
t = cputime;
...%your code
...%computing
...%when you are done
printf('Total cpu time: %f seconds\n', cputime-t);
```

In octave documentation we can use the `etime();`  function file, it returns the difference (in seconds) between two timestamps from the clock, like this:

```
t0 = clock ();
# many computations later...
elapsed_time = etime (clock (), t0);
```

What's the difference between the above two ways? The `etime` uses the hour of clock of my system? And what's a good way to collect the processing time of an code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code snippet with cputime measures the time your code was execuded on a CPU. The second snippet measures the wall clock time (btw: use tic and toc to measure this). The wall clock includes time where the CPU was executing some other threads or waiting for IO.

It is up to you what you want to measure. I normally use wall clock with tic/toc if I want to benchmark my code.

On single threaded apps the wall clock time is greater than or equal the cputime (because it includes the time the CPU was also processing some other threads). On multithreaded apps with multiple cores cputime can be greater than the wall clock time.